# Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for action mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I have been working with rails since a long. Now I am facing a small issue in the ActionMailer. I want to send an email when user gets registered to confirm his registration.
I am able to send email in the **development mode** but where as **not** in the **production mode.**

 the exception **Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)** is coming everytime when **deliver** method is called. 
I have written the following code. 
My SMTP config looks: 
      config.action_mailer.default_url_options =  { :host => "localhost:3000" }

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {   
    :openssl_verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE,      
    :ssl => true,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,  #this is the important stuff!
    :address        => 'smtp.xxxx.xxx',
    :port           => xxx,
    :domain         => 'xxxxxx',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => 'xxxxxxx@xxx.xxx',
    :password       => 'xxxxxxxxx'
  }
```

In the controller, I have written the following:

```
def confirm_registration_in_c       
 @user = User.find_by_email(asdf123@gmail.com)
 if @user
      UserMailer.confirm_registration(@user).deliver            
 end
end
```

In my user_mailer.rb :

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"

  def confirm_registration(user)
   @user = user
   @user_name = @user.name       
   email = @user.email 
   mail(:to => email, :subject => "Reset your password")
  end
end
```

**I am able to send email in the development mode in my local host, but I am not able to send the email in the dedicated server.**

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: See this: http://ramblinglabs.com/blog/2011/10/rails-3-1-smtp-gmail-errnoeconnrefused-connection-refuse

Answer (score 26):

In my situation, I encountered similar problems when I was trying to making through a sending-email Rails app tutorial,  the Heroku logs kept telling my that

`......`

`Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25):`

`......`

After I compared my code with author's code, I got to find out that I had not setup my ActionMailer configurations in the **config/environments/production.rb** file.

Then I came to realized that I just had my **config/environments/development.rb** configured for sending-email, but I had not done it for my **config/environments/production.rb**.

So you may check it when your app's behavior difers between development and production.

Comment: I made the same silly mistake. I had added the line `config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { address: "xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.com" }` in app/config/environments/development.rb but forgot to add it to app/config/environments/production.rb.

Answer (score 8):

Be sure you have configured your port correctly. I switched from gmail in development (port 587) to sending from my local server in production and was getting this error till I corrected the port to the one my server uses (port 25).

Answer (score 6):

My problem is not identical to this question, but I feel many would found this thread via google.

If you use external SMTP service like sendgrid and has set up ActionMailer accordingly, yet it still gives this error:

> Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25

You may be passing config hash with String key, which are ignored. Keys must be [symbols](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3220)!

This may happen if it is de-serialized, what I did is to ensure keys are symbols:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = get_smtp_setting.symbolize_keys
```

Comment: Even if this was not my problem it put me in the right direction: my configuration was not being loaded, a console execution of this `ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings` was showing me that the values were the default ones

Comment: @fguillen how did you fix it? Code?

Comment: This helped me go in the right direction. My issue was I had set `address: 'localhost'` instead of `address: '127.0.0.1'`.

Answer (score 5):

for production you cant write

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "localhost:3000" }
```

add production url for host, like,

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "http://www.yourdomain.com" }
```

Comment: did you restart the server after you make change?

Comment: Yes I have restarted the server after the changes made. But same error.

Comment: login into your gmail account(user_name      => 'xxxxxxx@xxx.xxx'). then restart the server

Comment: Is above mailer settings production.rb or ..?

Comment: I have written that mailer setting in the /config/application.rb file which is common for all.

Comment: And I have tried to put that mailer setting in the production.rb but the same issue is coming.

Answer (score 2):

There is another reason for this error:

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25
```

It should be looked at SENDMAIL service on your server:

- Is SENDMAIL installed?
- Is SENDMAIL running?

I had this error due to the stopped SENDMAIL.

Good luck!

Comment: I don't believe this person is using Sendmail, so this is not relevant.

Comment: I agree with you. But it had solved my problem, so it could be helpful to others.
:-)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with SendGrid and repeated `Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) )` Finally I modified the way smtp settings were set by changing the definition within `/config/environments/production.rb`
from:

```
    ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
```

to:

```
    config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
```

this did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I just tracked down a similar problem while trying to deploy wordpress with Capistrano.

`cap aborted!
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "{my-ip-address}" port {my-ssh-port}`

I would also get this similar error:

`Tasks: TOP => git:create_release
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: #<Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "my-ip-address" port {my-port}>`

It turns out it was an issue with concurrent SSH sessions as my server runs Fail2Ban. To solve that I simply did the following:

1. Edit the jail that contains SSH configurations

   `$ sudo nano /etc/fail2ban/jail.local`
2. look for [SSH] and set enabled = false
3. then find [ssh-ddos] and set enabled = false
4. Remember to restart Fail2Ban after your changes and open-ssh (if thats what your using)

`$ sudo service fail2ban reload`

`$ sudo /etc/init.d/ssh reload`

Its worth noting that the connection would be refused at different steps (tasks) in the deployment. For example after a reboot and a quick `bundle exec cap production deploy:check` everything appeared fine. Then I tried to deploy and received the same error, but during the execution of a different task. I also use UFW which I disabled and reenabled without issues. UFW was not the cause of the above problem.

I had a similar problem after I solved this. It was an issue with the `current` directory permissions. That's [over here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761003/how-can-i-get-capistrano-to-stop-failing-at-deploycreate-symlink/23718548#23718548)

Answer (score 0):

You may see a similar error message when using turbo_stream in rails 7 (or while doing the [rails 7 demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mpWFrUwAN88)).

If you do, run this and everything should work:

```sh
redis-server
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36155607/5783745).