# Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED) - Wercker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, continuous-integration, wercker

I'm using wercker for running specs of my rails app. I have problem with setting up redis on wercker. In my rails app I have `redis.rb` which looks like this:

```
if Figaro.env.rediscloud_url
  uri = URI.parse(Figaro.env.rediscloud_url)
  REDIS = Redis.new(host: uri.host, port: uri.port, password: uri.password)
elsif ENV['WERCKER_REDIS_HOST'] && ENV['WERCKER_REDIS_PORT']
  REDIS = Redis.new(host: ENV['WERCKER_REDIS_HOST'], port: ENV['WERCKER_REDIS_PORT'])
else
  REDIS = Redis.new
end
```

In wercker I set `WERCKER_REDIS_HOST` enviromental variable to: `127.0.0.1` and `WERCKER_REDIS_PORT` to `6379`

When I start my specs it returns:

```
 Redis::CannotConnectError:
Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
# /pipeline/cache/bundle-install/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.2.2/lib/redis/client.rb:332:in `rescue in establish_connection'
# /pipeline/cache/bundle-install/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.2.2/lib/redis/client.rb:318:in `establish_connection'
# /pipeline/cache/bundle-install/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.2.2/lib/redis/client.rb:94:in `block in connect'
# /pipeline/cache/bundle-install/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.2.2/lib/redis/client.rb:280:in `with_reconnect'
# /pipeline/cache/bundle-install/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.2.2/lib/redis/client.rb:93:in `connect'
# /pipeline/cache/bundle-install/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.2.2/lib/redis/client.rb:351:in `ensure_connected'
# /pipeline/cache/bundle-install/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.2.2/lib/redis/client.rb:208:in `block in process'
# /pipeline/cache/bundle-install/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.2.2/lib/redis/client.rb:293:in `logging'
# /pipeline/cache/bundle-install/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.2.2/lib/redis/client.rb:207:in `process'
# /pipeline/cache/bundle-install/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.2.2/lib/redis/client.rb:178:in `call_pipelined'
# /pipeline/cache/bundle-install/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.2.2/lib/redis/client.rb:150:in `block in call_pipeline'
# /pipeline/cache/bundle-install/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.2.2/lib/redis/client.rb:280:in `with_reconnect'
# /pipeline/cache/bundle-install/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.2.2/lib/redis/client.rb:148:in `call_pipeline'
# /pipeline/cache/bundle-install/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.2.2/lib/redis.rb:2245:in `block in multi'
# /pipeline/cache/bundle-install/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.2.2/lib/redis.rb:57:in `block in synchronize'
# /pipeline/cache/bundle-install/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.2.2/lib/redis.rb:57:in `synchronize'
# /pipeline/cache/bundle-install/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.2.2/lib/redis.rb:2237:in `multi'
# /pipeline/cache/bundle-install/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.0/lib/sidekiq/client.rb:171:in `block in raw_push'
# /pipeline/cache/bundle-install/ruby/2.3.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.0/lib/connection_pool.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in with'
# /pipeline/cache/bundle-install/ruby/2.3.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.0/lib/connection_pool.rb:63:in `handle_interrupt'
# /pipeline/cache/bundle-install/ruby/2.3.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.0/lib/connection_pool.rb:63:in `block in with'
# /pipeline/cache/bundle-install/ruby/2.3.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.0/lib/connection_pool.rb:60:in `handle_interrupt'
# /pipeline/cache/bundle-install/ruby/2.3.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.0/lib/connection_pool.rb:60:in `with'
# /pipeline/cache/bundle-install/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.0/lib/sidekiq/client.rb:170:in `raw_push'
# /pipeline/cache/bundle-install/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.0/lib/sidekiq/client.rb:67:in `push'
# /pipeline/cache/bundle-install/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.0/lib/sidekiq/worker.rb:115:in `client_push'
# /pipeline/cache/bundle-install/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.0/lib/sidekiq/extensions/generic_proxy.rb:19:in `method_missing'
# ./app/models/user.rb:26:in `send_reset_password_instructions'
# ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:43:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
# ------------------
# --- Caused by: ---
# IO::EINPROGRESSWaitWritable:
# Operation now in progress - connect(2) would block
# /pipeline/cache/bundle-install/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.2.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:122:in `connect_addrinfo'
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Does it work if you add a sleep before connecting? I have seen cases where the startup of redis or mysql takes a bit longer and the build steps try accessing it too fast. There is a `service-ready` step or sthg similar, use that.

Comment: double checked it - the step is called `service-check`: https://app.wercker.com/#applications/565702a38faa27fb0d1db58a/tab/details/

Answer (score 33):

I had the same problem, but I found a fix:

Start Redis manually in terminal with `redis-server`

Comment: This is not the question.

Comment: Thanks @Mirror318!

Comment: sudo systemctl start redis-server

Comment: Worked! Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me. Anyone know why this works? I can even close the terminal window that I ran `redis-server` in and the original error message never returns (unless I restart my macbook). I guess redis keeps running in the background?

Answer (score 21):

I had the same issue and the steps I used to solve this in Mac OSX Catalina were:

1. Install redis (if not installed)

```
brew install redis
```

2. Start the redis server (thanks @Mirror318)

```
redis-server
```

or to start in background

```
# By default Redis does not run as a daemon. Use 'yes' to use it
redis-server --daemonize yes
```

Answer (score 12):

You may also need to install redis-server

```
$ sudo apt install redis-server
```

Comment: If you are on a Mac and are using Homebrew, you can simply run `brew install redis`, and you'll be good to go. (It fixed it for me, anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

REDIS might not be installed

```
sudo apt install redis-server
```

If you're on MAC

```
brew install redis
```

Start the server by

```
redis-server
```

Sometimes, REDIS server can run out memory due to unexpected load or if you're on server side CPU utilization. You can see the exact cause of this

```
sudo systemctl status redis-server
```

For logs,

```
journalctl -u redis-server.service
```

To Restart the server

```
sudo systemctl restart redis-server
```