# Port 587 blocked on Ubuntu VPS... can't unblock it...what to do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, smtp, capistrano, figaro-ruby

My app can't send order invoices and gives this error in the `production.log`:

```
I, [2017-05-21T17:17:19.539388 #9385]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 26ms (ActiveRecord: 3.1ms)
F, [2017-05-21T17:17:19.540462 #9385] FATAL -- :
Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2) for nil port 587):
  app/admin/order.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

My cloud services support sent me this answer : `I ran an NMAP on your IP address and port 587 appears to be blocked locally on your Droplet. Usually this is caused by IPtables or UFW trying to be helpful, but actually blocking a needed port.`

So I did `sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 587  -j ACCEPT` and `sudo ufw allow out 587`

That didn't do the trick  and I'm still getting this error.
Can someone please advise me?

here is the `action mailer`settings in the `production.rb`

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'mypage.com'}
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: ENV["SMTP_ADDRESS"],
    user_name: ENV["SMTP_USER"],
    password: ENV["SMTP_PASSWORD"],
    domain: "mypage.com",
    port: 587,
    authentication: :login,
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
```

In the `deploy.rb` I have this line to to trigger a copy of figaros `application.yml` to the server.

```
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml config/secrets.yml config/application.yml}
```

I'm using `figaro gem`
in the `application.yml` there is this lines:

```
    SMTP_ADDRESS: "smtp.gmail.com"
SMTP_USER: "xxx@xxxx.com"
SMTP_PASSWORD: "xxxxxx"
```

** UPdate-3**

```
        I, [2017-05-23T11:01:33.056948 #1060]  INFO -- : Started GET "/admin/orders/10/edit" for 89.160.235.185 at 2017-05-23 11:01:33 +0000
    I, [2017-05-23T11:01:33.063914 #1060]  INFO -- : Processing by Admin::OrdersController#edit as HTML
    I, [2017-05-23T11:01:33.064026 #1060]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"id"=>"10"}
    D, [2017-05-23T11:01:33.067956 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36mCart Load (0.5ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1^[[0m  [["$
    D, [2017-05-23T11:01:33.072547 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35mAdminUser Load (0.4ms)^[[0m  SELECT  "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."id" = $1$
    D, [2017-05-23T11:01:33.075089 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36mOrder Load (0.3ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1^[[0m $
    D, [2017-05-23T11:01:33.119522 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35mCACHE (0.0ms)^[[0m  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "10"]]
    I, [2017-05-23T11:01:33.235247 #1060]  INFO -- :   Rendered /home/deploy/hlinreykdal/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-0a5a15b88bff/app/views/activ$
    I, [2017-05-23T11:01:33.235589 #1060]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 171ms (Views: 157.9ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
    I, [2017-05-23T11:01:36.922087 #1060]  INFO -- : Started PATCH "/admin/orders/10" for 89.160.235.185 at 2017-05-23 11:01:36 +0000
    I, [2017-05-23T11:01:36.924303 #1060]  INFO -- : Processing by Admin::OrdersController#update as HTML
    I, [2017-05-23T11:01:36.924405 #1060]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>" ^ ^ ", "authenticity_token"=>"f8ApZNwgnz1TpSUFfXOkVb2/QnTZaz2p0j3cWIcmdBxRzZpmmWJLQmuDx+n$
    D, [2017-05-23T11:01:36.925594 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36mCart Load (0.2ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1^[[0m  [["$
    D, [2017-05-23T11:01:36.926750 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35mAdminUser Load (0.2ms)^[[0m  SELECT  "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."id" = $1$
    D, [2017-05-23T11:01:36.957134 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36mOrder Load (0.3ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1^[[0m $
    D, [2017-05-23T11:01:36.958757 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35m (0.1ms)^[[0m  BEGIN
    D, [2017-05-23T11:01:36.961249 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36mSQL (0.6ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mUPDATE "orders" SET "shipped" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "orders"."id" = $3$
    D, [2017-05-23T11:01:36.962569 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35m (0.8ms)^[[0m  COMMIT
    I, [2017-05-23T11:01:36.965057 #1060]  INFO -- : Redirected to http://hlinreykdal.com/admin/orders/10
    I, [2017-05-23T11:01:36.965267 #1060]  INFO -- : Completed 302 Found in 41ms (ActiveRecord: 2.3ms)
    I, [2017-05-23T11:01:37.013697 #1060]  INFO -- : Started GET "/admin/orders/10" for 89.160.235.185 at 2017-05-23 11:01:37 +0000
    I, [2017-05-23T11:01:37.014844 #1060]  INFO -- : Processing by Admin::OrdersController#show as HTML
    I, [2017-05-23T11:01:37.014925 #1060]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"id"=>"10"}
    D, [2017-05-23T11:01:37.015893 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36mCart Load (0.2ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1^[[0m  [["$
    D, [2017-05-23T11:01:37.017087 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35mAdminUser Load (0.2ms)^[[0m  SELECT  "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."id" = $1$
    D, [2017-05-23T11:01:37.017985 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36mOrder Load (0.2ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1^[[0m $
    D, [2017-05-23T11:01:37.046277 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35mProductItem Load (0.9ms)^[[0m  SELECT "product_items".* FROM "product_items" WHERE "product_items"."o$
    D, [2017-05-23T11:01:37.048060 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36mProduct Load (0.3ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = $1 LIMIT$
    I, [2017-05-23T11:01:37.055910 #1060]  INFO -- :   Rendered /home/deploy/hlinreykdal/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-0a5a15b88bff/app/views/activ$
    I, [2017-05-23T11:01:37.056193 #1060]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 41ms (Views: 36.4ms | ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)
    I, [2017-05-23T11:01:39.569747 #1060]  INFO -- : Started GET "/admin/orders" for 89.160.235.185 at 2017-05-23 11:01:39 +0000
    I, [2017-05-23T11:01:39.571136 #1060]  INFO -- : Processing by Admin::OrdersController#index as HTML
    D, [2017-05-23T11:01:39.572365 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35mCart Load (0.2ms)^[[0m  SELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 45856$
    D, [2017-05-23T11:01:39.573735 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36mAdminUser Load (0.2ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT  "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."id"$
    D, [2017-05-23T11:01:39.601594 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35m (0.6ms)^[[0m  SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT  1 AS count_column FROM "orders" LIMIT 30 OFFS$
    D, [2017-05-23T11:01:39.602587 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36mCACHE (0.0ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT  1 AS count_column FROM "orders" LIM$
    D, [2017-05-23T11:01:39.603970 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35m (0.3ms)^[[0m  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "orders"
    D, [2017-05-23T11:01:39.605077 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36mCACHE (0.0ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT  1 AS count_column FROM "orders" LIM$
    D, [2017-05-23T11:01:39.607023 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35mOrder Load (0.4ms)^[[0m  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders"  ORDER BY "orders"."id" desc LIMIT 30 OFFSE$
    D, [2017-05-23T11:01:39.630054 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36mProductItem Load (0.4ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT "product_items".* FROM "product_items"^[[0m
I, [2017-05-23T11:01:39.675343 #1060]  INFO -- :   Rendered /home/deploy/hlinreykdal/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-0a5a15b88bff/app/views/activ$
I, [2017-05-23T11:01:39.675662 #1060]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 104ms (Views: 98.1ms | ActiveRecord: 2.2ms)
I, [2017-05-23T11:01:42.003418 #1060]  INFO -- : Started GET "/admin/orders/10/edit" for 89.160.235.185 at 2017-05-23 11:01:42 +0000
I, [2017-05-23T11:01:42.005829 #1060]  INFO -- : Processing by Admin::OrdersController#edit as HTML
I, [2017-05-23T11:01:42.005923 #1060]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"id"=>"10"}
D, [2017-05-23T11:01:42.007115 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35mCart Load (0.2ms)^[[0m  SELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 45856$
D, [2017-05-23T11:01:42.008543 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36mAdminUser Load (0.2ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT  "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."id"$
D, [2017-05-23T11:01:42.009473 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35mOrder Load (0.2ms)^[[0m  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1$
D, [2017-05-23T11:01:42.030642 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36mCACHE (0.0ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1^[[0m  [["i$
I, [2017-05-23T11:01:42.096028 #1060]  INFO -- :   Rendered /home/deploy/hlinreykdal/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-0a5a15b88bff/app/views/activ$
I, [2017-05-23T11:01:42.096369 #1060]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 90ms (Views: 86.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
I, [2017-05-23T11:01:44.668194 #1060]  INFO -- : Started PATCH "/admin/orders/10" for 89.160.235.185 at 2017-05-23 11:01:44 +0000
I, [2017-05-23T11:01:44.674148 #1060]  INFO -- : Processing by Admin::OrdersController#update as HTML
I, [2017-05-23T11:01:44.674417 #1060]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>" ^ ^ ", "authenticity_token"=>"NcVZXJWZ1pcKMTEmFFZmtY3HvY7oJH2G+WOxTpVXu6UbyOpe0NsC6DIX08q$
D, [2017-05-23T11:01:44.681838 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35mCart Load (1.6ms)^[[0m  SELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 45856$
D, [2017-05-23T11:01:44.687054 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36mAdminUser Load (0.4ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT  "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."id"$
D, [2017-05-23T11:01:44.690370 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35mOrder Load (0.4ms)^[[0m  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1$
D, [2017-05-23T11:01:44.694556 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36m (0.1ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mBEGIN^[[0m
D, [2017-05-23T11:01:44.699039 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35mSQL (0.4ms)^[[0m  UPDATE "orders" SET "shipped" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "orders"."id" = $3  [["$
D, [2017-05-23T11:01:44.700660 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36m (0.7ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mCOMMIT^[[0m
I, [2017-05-23T11:01:44.703571 #1060]  INFO -- : SMTP_ADDR: "smtp.gmail.com"
D, [2017-05-23T11:01:44.707271 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35mProductItem Load (0.3ms)^[[0m  SELECT "product_items".* FROM "product_items" WHERE "product_items"."o$
D, [2017-05-23T11:01:44.708898 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36mProduct Load (0.3ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = $1 LIMIT$
I, [2017-05-23T11:01:44.709746 #1060]  INFO -- :   Rendered order_notifier/shipped.html.erb within layouts/mailer (4.5ms)
D, [2017-05-23T11:01:44.711077 #1060] DEBUG -- :
OrderNotifier#shipped: processed outbound mail in 8.1ms
I, [2017-05-23T11:01:44.739622 #1060]  INFO -- :
Sent mail to dadih32@gmail.com (28.3ms)
D, [2017-05-23T11:01:44.739727 #1060] DEBUG -- : Date: Tue, 23 May 2017 11:01:44 +0000
From: =?UTF-8?B?SGzDrW4=?= Reykdal Concept Store <hlin@hlinreykdal.com>
To: dadih32@gmail.com
Message-ID: <59241698ae5b8_4242ad89726e92861420@hlinreykdal.mail>
Subject: Order Shipped
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Your Order has been shipped</h1>

<h3>Dear dadi </h3>


<p>
 Your order has been shipped to your address, please contact store@hlinreykdal.com for further information.
</p>

<p> Thank You </p>

        <ul>
                <li>
                        FOLLY MATCHBOOK NAIL FILES&times;1
                </li>


        </ul>

<p> Thank You </p>





  </body>
</html>

I, [2017-05-23T11:01:44.741054 #1060]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 66ms (ActiveRecord: 4.2ms)
F, [2017-05-23T11:01:44.743481 #1060] FATAL -- :
SocketError (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known):
  app/admin/order.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

I, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.863192 #1060]  INFO -- : Started GET "/products/41" for 164.132.161.46 at 2017-05-23 11:10:08 +0000
I, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.876373 #1060]  INFO -- : Processing by ProductsController#show as */*
I, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.876536 #1060]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"id"=>"41"}
D, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.881123 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35mCart Load (0.7ms)^[[0m  SELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", nil]]
D, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.882685 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36m (0.2ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mBEGIN^[[0m
D, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.887770 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35mSQL (1.3ms)^[[0m  INSERT INTO "carts" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [[$
D, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.890018 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36m (0.7ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mCOMMIT^[[0m
D, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.893274 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35mProduct Load (1.2ms)^[[0m  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."slug" = $1  ORDER B$
D, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.894865 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36mProduct Load (0.4ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = $1 LIMIT$
D, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.900733 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35mLabel Load (1.2ms)^[[0m  SELECT  "labels".* FROM "labels" WHERE "labels"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 8$
D, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.907954 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36mProduct Load (0.6ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."category_id" =$
I, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.916955 #1060]  INFO -- :   Rendered products/show.html.erb within layouts/application (18.7ms)
D, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.920965 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35mCategory Load (0.8ms)^[[0m  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
D, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.924524 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36mLabel Load (0.3ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT "labels".* FROM "labels"^[[0m
D, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.929926 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35m (0.3ms)^[[0m  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "product_items" WHERE "product_items"."cart_id" = $1  [["cart_id"$
I, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.930159 #1060]  INFO -- :   Rendered application/_navbar.html.erb (10.7ms)
I, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.931046 #1060]  INFO -- :   Rendered application/_message.html.erb (0.2ms)
I, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.932261 #1060]  INFO -- :   Rendered emaillist/_email.html.erb (0.6ms)
I, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.932381 #1060]  INFO -- :   Rendered application/_notifications.html.erb (0.9ms)
I, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.936424 #1060]  INFO -- :   Rendered application/_footer.html.erb (3.5ms)
I, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.936826 #1060]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 60ms (Views: 36.7ms | ActiveRecord: 7.6ms)
I, [2017-05-23T11:12:35.005157 #1060]  INFO -- : Started GET "/labels/10" for 66.249.65.74 at 2017-05-23 11:12:35 +0000
I, [2017-05-23T11:12:35.040137 #1060]  INFO -- : Processing by LabelsController#show as HTML
I, [2017-05-23T11:12:35.040544 #1060]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"id"=>"10"}
D, [2017-05-23T11:12:35.049755 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36mCart Load (0.8ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1^[[0m  [["$
D, [2017-05-23T11:12:35.052776 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35m (0.2ms)^[[0m  BEGIN
D, [2017-05-23T11:12:35.060048 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36mSQL (0.9ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mINSERT INTO "carts" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id$
D, [2017-05-23T11:12:35.061486 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35m (0.6ms)^[[0m  COMMIT
D, [2017-05-23T11:12:35.065373 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36mLabel Load (0.4ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT  "labels".* FROM "labels" WHERE "labels"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1^[[0m $
I, [2017-05-23T11:12:35.067624 #1060]  INFO -- : Completed 404 Not Found in 27ms (ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)
F, [2017-05-23T11:12:35.069957 #1060] FATAL -- :
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Label with 'id'=10):
  app/controllers/labels_controller.rb:21:in `set_label'
```

Comment: Are you sure that `ENV["SMTP_ADDRESS"]` is not `nil`? See also [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38677793/errnoeconnrefused-connection-refused-connect2-for-nil-port-587-for-rail) (with the same error).

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is not nil... in my `application.yml` it is set as `SMTP_ADDRESS: "smtp.gmail.com"`

Comment: OK and how do you convert the `application.yml` to `ENV` variables? Are you using the [figaro gem](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) or something like that? Can you pls confirm that the variable is indeed set by showing `puts ENV["SMTP_ADDRESS"].inspect` just before sending the mail?

Comment: I'm using `figaro gem`.... this is the output `irb(main):001:0> puts ENV["SMTP_ADDRESS"].inspect
"smtp.gmail.com"
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> 
`

Comment: OK and can you put the same inspect inside the `production.rb` file, please? I suspect that the Figaro gem is initialized / or the `application.yml` file read _after_ running through the `production.rb` file.

Comment: ok if I do that I get this error now form the `production.log` : `SocketError (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known):
  app/admin/order.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'`

Comment: Either read the output from the console (`puts` prints to console), or please change the `production.log` debug line to: `Rails.logger.info "SMTP_ADDR: #{ENV["SMTP_ADDRESS"].inspect}"` and paste here the output from the log. I expect that it will be blank (`nil`). Thanks.

Comment: here it is `irb(main):002:0> Rails.logger.info "SMTP_ADDR: #{ENV["SMTP_ADDRESS"].inspect}"
SMTP_ADDR: "smtp.gmail.com"
=> true
`

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean 'rails c' console but stdout console. If you don't know what I mean, please use the line in priduction.rb and read the result from the production.logm thanks,

Comment: If I add the line to production.rb the deploy breaks with `undefined method  info`

Comment: how can I access this `stdout console`through my terminal?

Comment: OK I have to say I did not know that logger is not available yet in the environment files. I tested it and indeed it's not. However you can easily configure one right away: in the `production.log`, replace the log line with two lines: `config.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new('/tmp/foo.log')` and `config.logger.info "SMTP_ADDR: #{ENV["SMTP_ADDRESS"].inspect}"`, deploy and inspect the `/tmp/foo.log` file content.

Comment: I don´t see any `foo.log` though in the `deploy@superapp:~/superapp/current/tmp$`

Comment: It should be present in `/tmp`, the server-wide tmp directory. Try `cat /tmp/foo.log`.

Comment: thank you, please see my update....I added the ` foo.log`output to my question.   I had to shorten it due to length....

Comment: OK, thanks, but I'm sorry, my original assumption was wrong and the config variable is indeed set properly. Now, when you log on the server, can you do `host smtp.gmail.com` and get the IP address properly without errors? Can you also pls paste the content of `order.rb`, especially around line 6?

Comment: thanks man... here isn the output of `host smtp.gmail.com`    `smtp.gmail.com is an alias for gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com has address 74.125.71.108
gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com has address 74.125.71.109
gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com has IPv6 address 2a00:1450:400c:c02::6d`         The order.rb has been added to the question

Comment: Thank you, so DNS also works ok. Now, can you do `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587` without connection errors (run this on the production server, of course)?

Comment: It works `Trying 74.125.71.108...
Connected to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP k22sm2411466wrc.12 - gsmtp`

Comment: Hmmm, then I guess it must be something else... Could you pls edit `config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb` and uncomment the `remove_silencers!` line, deploy and paste here the full stack trace fo the error? Thanks.

Comment: Hi,  please see update-3

Comment: Are you sure you ran the project with the silencers removed? The output from update3 has no new information, there should be many more lines with the stack trace...

Comment: Yes I uncommented this line `Rails.backtrace_cleaner.remove_silencers!` I've restarted the server please see update-3 again

Comment: I added another question about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44155659/serious-problems-sending-mails-via-actionmailer-in-production-ror

Comment: thank you for all your help and time... this problem has been solved https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44155659/serious-problems-sending-mails-via-actionmailer-in-production-ror/44156539#44156539

Comment: That's great news! I have to say I was slowly getting a bit desperate as nothung made sense to me... So, in the end, was it all about the `.inspect` that you somehow did not include in this original question? ;-) Even if so, never mind and I'm glad that you've resolved the issue!