# serious problems sending mails via actionmailer in production ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, smtp, actionmailer

I really need help with this, have been trying to work this out for 3 days :(
My app is supposed to send emails to customer when order is either received or shipped but it constantly breaks with this error.

```
  I, [2017-05-23T11:01:44.741054 #1060]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 66ms (ActiveRecord: 4.2ms)
F, [2017-05-23T11:01:44.743481 #1060] FATAL -- :
SocketError (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known):
  app/admin/order.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

My `actionmailer`setup seems to be right:

```
      config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'mypage.com'}
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: ENV["SMTP_ADDRESS"].inspect,
    user_name: ENV["SMTP_USER"],
    password: ENV["SMTP_PASSWORD"],
    domain: "mypage.com",
    port: 587,
    authentication: :login,
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
```

The `ENV`variables are stored in the `application.yml`

```
SMTP_ADDRESS: "smtp.gmail.com"
SMTP_USER: "xxx@xxxxxxxxxx.com"
SMTP_PASSWORD: "xxxxxxxx"
```

The `ENV`variables have been checked by running:

```
Loading production environment (Rails 4.2.5)
irb(main):001:0> puts ENV["SMTP_ADDRESS"].inspect 
"smtp.gmail.com"
=> nil
irb(main):002:0>
```

I have done `host smtp.gmail.com` with positive resault:

```
smtp.gmail.com is an alias for gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com has address 74.125.206.108
gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com has address 74.125.206.109
gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com has IPv6 address 2a00:1450:400c:c04::6d
```

I've done `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587`:

```
Trying 74.125.206.108...
Connected to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP c17sm3264999wre.35 - gsmtp
```

I've also done `nslookup smtp.gmail.com`:

```
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
smtp.gmail.com  canonical name = gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
Name:   gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com
Address: 74.125.206.108
Name:   gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com
Address: 74.125.206.109
```

I'm running out of options here, this works perfectly locally were `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }`

But after deploy `actionmailer`breaks.

In my google account, I've `https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha` and enabled `less secure apps`  with out luck.

Below is the `admin/order.rb` were the error is raised for line: 6.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Order do

permit_params :shipped

after_update do |order|
    OrderNotifier.shipped(@order).deliver if order.shipped  #this is line 6.

end

show do |order|



    panel 'Customer Details' do
        attributes_table_for order, :name, :email, :address, :city, :country
    end

    panel 'Created' do
        "#{time_ago_in_words order.created_at} ago"
    end


    panel 'Shipped' do
        order.shipped
    end

    panel 'Order Details' do
        table_for(order.product_items) do 
            column 'Product' do |item|
                item.product.title
            end
            column 'Quantity' do |item|
                item.quantity
            end
            column 'Price Isl' do |item|
                number_to_currency item.total_price_isl
            end
            column 'Price USD' do |item|
                number_to_currency item.total_price_usd
            end
        end
    end

    panel 'Order Total USD' do 
        number_to_currency order.total_price_usd

    end

    panel 'Order Total Iskr' do 
        number_to_currency order.total_price_isl

    end

end


end
```

here is the `mailer/order_notifier.rb`

```
 class OrderNotifier < ApplicationMailer

  default from: 'Concept Store <mail@mypage.com>'

  def received(order)
    @order = order

    mail to: order.email, subject: 'Concept Store'
  end


  def shipped(order)

   @order = order

    mail to: order.email, subject: 'Order Shipped'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder if this is just as simple as the following:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  # address: ENV["SMTP_ADDRESS"].inspect,
  address: ENV["SMTP_ADDRESS"],
  # ...
}
```

- because `inspect` adds quotes to the string (see below):

  ```
  puts "somestring"
  # => somestring
  puts "somestring".inspect
  # => "somestring"
  ```

Comment: You are my hero today :) .... that was it....so simple.. thank you so much